# How do I change the number of rows that output in the console?

Tags: r

I'm using RStudio Server and the number of rows in the console is limited to 1000.

I'd like to increase the limit to 3000. I tried running this command `rstudioapi::writeRStudioPreference("console_max_lines", 3000)` .

I also tried going to settings and then code and then display and choose `Limit length of lines displayed in the console` = 3000. I clicked apply and then save.

I restarted my R Session and I'm still limited to 1,000 lines.

Comment: [`options`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/options.html)`(max.print=3000)`?

Comment: That didn't work either

Comment: Try this: `options(max.print=32); mtcars; options(max.print=33); mtcars`. What it's doing is showing 32 and then 33 "things": since `mtcars` has 11 columns, then when set to 32, it cannot show a complete row 3 without exceeding the set of 32.